# col-xl-12 is not 100% of div father

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why `inew2` and `inew3` not have 100% width of his div father? https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4GEa.jpg

```css
html, body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.ibrands{
 height: 120px;
 background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

.navbar {
 height: 80px;
}
.inew1{
 height: 720px;
 background: red;

}
.inew2{
 height: 360px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
.inew3{
 height: 360px;
}
.ibrands a{
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px; 
}
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid"> 
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 inew1 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
              <h1 class="">Título</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veritatis repudiandae unde, placeat iste eaque omnis necessitatibus, ratione, distinctio laboriosam rem, at porro aut saepe quia. Voluptas dicta alias, molestiae!</p>
          </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xl-12 inew2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
                            <h1 class="">Títle2</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi dolores accusantium, eius inventore nemo molestiae dolore ex voluptates et aut incidunt eligendi vel asperiores maxime soluta tenetur id exercitationem magnam!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-12 inew3 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
                            <h1 class="">Títle3</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi dolores accusantium, eius inventore nemo molestiae dolore ex voluptates et aut incidunt eligendi vel asperiores maxime soluta tenetur id exercitationem magnam!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row ibrands">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
            <a href="" class="">a</a>
            <a href="" class="">b</a>
            <a href="" class="">s</a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.row` when nesting. It will take away the extra margin left and right.

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 inew2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
                        <h1 class="">Títle2</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi dolores accusantium, eius inventore nemo molestiae dolore ex voluptates et aut incidunt eligendi vel asperiores maxime soluta tenetur id exercitationem magnam!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 inew3 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
                        <h1 class="">Títle3</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi dolores accusantium, eius inventore nemo molestiae dolore ex voluptates et aut incidunt eligendi vel asperiores maxime soluta tenetur id exercitationem magnam!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```